# How to play YouTube videos in google chromecast from Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, youtube, video-streaming, chromecast, flutter-video-player

My Flutter application has some YouTube video links. Those YouTube links, i would like to stream through google chromecast. I have seen some video stream casting using the below flutter libraries.

- https://pub.dev/packages/cast
- https://pub.dev/packages/dart_chromecast

But those libraries are playing MP4 format video streaming. So i am searching for the way to play YouTube videos though flutter application in chromecast.

Please someone suggest me if there is any code clues for this.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same challenge, and we searched high and low. Finally found this solution to make it work: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_chromecast

Make sure your flutter compiler is downgraded to 13 or below. Otherwise, you will not be able to compile. Unfortunately, their code is not supported in a newer version of the flutter compiler and the author is not going to update anytime soon.