# How to cast screen from flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on flutter app where I playing live videos. Now I want to cast my device screen using Roku, FireTv, Chromecast and Airplay. I want to know is it possible cast screen using these technologies? I used [cast](https://pub.dev/packages/cast) dart package to discover and connect with chromecast devices but not able to scan any device. Please help me how it working with flutter?

Thanks Advance.

Comment: you can implement it in native side

Comment: Any possible solution in flutter side.

Comment: @GursewakSingh Did you get any solution for screencasting?

Answer (score 1):

We were able to make it work on Chromecast, see my answer posted here:
[How to play YouTube videos in google chromecast from Flutter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475857/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-google-chromecast-from-flutter-application/68194357#68194357)

As for Airplay, if you use updated Apple libraries, Airplay will be integrated natively into your app. We were able to cast our app to Airplay without having to add extra code.

FireTV uses airplay so that should work.

We have not found a Roku solution yet.

Comment: How do you update Apple libraries within the flutter app? I've used this package to trigger native airplay view within the app. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_to_airplay

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether it is working or not. just catch this url from internet. try this
https://morioh.com/p/fbd0079a2d71

and another example i got. i didn't check this also
https://github.com/terrabythia/flutter_chromecast_example